# Installing Angular-CLI on Windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, windows-10

I had installation issues of angular-cli on Windows 10 system. 
    The errors were related to Python dependencies and node-gyp. Something as below :

```
>execSync@1.0.2 install C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\execSync
node install.js
[execsync v1.0.2] Attempting to compile native extensions.
{ Error: spawn node-gyp ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1007:11)
```

Answer (score 8):

**Update**

this seems to be fixed in newer releases and this solution is no longer required.

---

mukesh51 eventually solved the problem.

the installation seems to work in these steps:

1. `npm install -g node-gyp`
2. `npm install -g windows-build-tools`
3. `npm install -g @angular/cli`

I took these steps from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2341#issuecomment-249853185).

Answer (score 5):

**Uninstall**

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
```

**Update Global package**

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should format your commands as code to make it easier to read and explain your answer a bit.

Answer (score 3):

I too faced the same issue initially when I installed angular directly using bash. The installation was error completely. Then I attempted to install locally in my project (without removing the global one). That appeared to have solved the problem but got an error on creating a new app.

So i uninstalled everything :

```
 npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

and the reinstalled **Angular using Windows Power Shell(as Admin)**

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

This solved the entire problem! Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Use windows power shell to install angular-cli. It will run without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

**Windows 10 Solution**

Look back at the trace of installation steps ... you may see that it found the Angular binary in the following location:

***C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin***

I added an ENVT variable using this path and **ng** worked fine after that

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `npm install -g @angular/cli`
npm downloaded files successfully and copied files to AppData but not able to use `ng -v`
After that, I tried following:

`npm cache clean --force`

Removes npm cache forcefully if you get warning using `npm cache clean`.

Then try

`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

I have successfully installed by trying the above solution in Windows10.

Answer (score 0):

Both the CLI and generated project have dependencies that require Node 8.9 or higher, together with NPM 5.5.1 or higher.

try update node.js and npm

Answer (score 0):

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli

- if doesn't work: 
  Close the terminal, open a new one or use CMD or Git for windows instead.